# systemd-resolved dns over https (doh) with custom port and domain

Tags: networking, dns

I want to use dns over https (doh) on my system (Ubuntu 22 LTS) and connect to a server ([smartSNI](https://github.com/bepass-org/smartSNI)) which is listening on port 9443, but the DNS resolution doesn't work correctly.

`resolvectl --version` returns systemd 249 (249.11-0ubuntu3.12), I think it should support doh.

The /etc/systemd/resolved.conf :

```
[Resolve]
DNS=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9443#subdomain.domain.com/dns-query
DNSOverTLS=yes
```

The /etc/resolv.conf contains this line `nameserver 127.0.0.53`

After `systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service` , my DNS resolving doesn't work correctly. What should I do?

Comment: Read the fine manual `man resolved.conf` to see what is supported. Semantics matter in the manual and where it says `DNSOverTLS` it means DNS over TLS or `DoT` and means exactly that and not DNS over HTTP(s)  `DoH` - smartsni seems to support both

Comment: @HBruijn How can I modify my settings? smartSNI didn't provide information about differences between DoH and DoT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

systemd-resolved [does not support DNS over HTTPS yet](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8639).

You can use DNS over TLS, but it's not the HTTP protocol format and uses port 853:

```ini
# /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
[Resolve]
DNS=8.8.8.8#dns.google
FallbackDNS=8.8.4.4#dns.google
Domains=~.
DNSSEC=yes
DNSOverTLS=yes
```

If you really need DNS over the HTTPS protocol (port 443 or any other port), you can explore `dnsmasq`.

Comment: Thanks dear Daniel. you're right I solved my problem using dnsmasq. I found this repo (which could be useful for others and I write it's link:) https://github.com/M-Ahadi/dockers/tree/master/Smart%20DNS